# How can I add style effect for elements inside of echo using classes?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with adding style effect for div elements inside of  echo, here's my code:

```
<?php
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDataBase;charset=utf8','user','password');

$response=$db->query('select * from users order by ID desc limit 10');
while($line=$reponse->fetch())
{
    echo 
        '<div class="elements" ><h1>'.$line['pseudo'].'</h1></div>
        <div class="elements">'.$line['message'].'</div>
        </div>';

} ?>
```

and the stylesheet:

```
.elements{
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
    }
```

when I execute it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you notice there's a starting div missing in your loop?

Comment: html source/console reveals what? an error, right?

Comment: you also have a syntax error `$reponse` != `$response`

Comment: It's an html & css issue, not php. Try to put "color: blue;" in your css and say us if the color change. If it doesn't change, your css file is not on your page.

Comment: @ThomasRbt it is a "php" issue; look at my comment up there.

Comment: this is a typo question; on 2 counts and error reporting would have been your friend today

Comment: the `!=` means => "does not equal" btw.

Comment: You have to include the stylesheet file in your HTML code. Also note that the style of `<h1>` will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. Just inline your php as needed into the html code to display on the page. For Example:

```
<?php

Inlcude your php and queries here in this block 


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo '<div class="elements">the rest of your php code goes here</div> '; ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is just bare bones basic code to show you what I am talking about. So your custom css would live in the styles.css file. Once you echo out what it is you want in php, then it will inherit those styles. You can inline php as much as you want throughout the file. Just name it file.php or whatever you want.

This will allow you to do what it is you are asking. Of course you could reverse this and echo out the html from start to finish if you really wanted too, but it would be easier to just add the relevant connection info for php and query at the top of the page before any html and then echo out the specific information you wish inside the html below the main php code.

Also I noticed you have one too many closing div tags at the bottom of your echo statement. As others have already commented, you have some other errors as well.

Comment: thank you very much for your help ,it works now ,in addition to some errors i had in my code ,please accept my sincere apologies for my incoherent code ,i made a lot of silly faults in my question ,the best of all , i didn't copy it correctly for exemple the missing <div> and response ,those one  were correct in my code,anyway you've been so helpful for me thanks again

Comment: Your very welcome, feel free to mark the correct answer with the check mark or upvote the answer as well. See you around and glad I could help